# cd Command in ConEmu and MinGW

Tags: linux, bash, conemu, mingw

I'm running `MinGW bash` in ConEmu and have set the `HOME` variable to my desired directory  `c/Users/<username>` in the `MinGW/msys/1.0/etc/profile` file.  The problem is that when I enter `cd` in ConEmu, it appends the `HOME` directory to the current one.   For example, if I start ConEmu and run `cd`, it changes to the (nonexistant) directory `c/Users/<username>/c/Users/<username>`.  Furthermore, once in this directory, running `cd` again results in the error `bash.exe": cd: c/Users/<username>: No such file or directory`.

This is not an issue in the Git Bash shell that came with `MinGW`, so I'm pretty sure this is an issue with ConEmu.

Comment: Have you checked if `alias` brings up anything relevant?

Comment: Actually, I don't believe you can't reproduce the same without ConEmu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root directory on Unix is `/`.  Normally, Unix commands will try to open files and directories relative to the current directory if your path does not start with `/`.

It seems like running `cd` in bash is currently trying to look for a directory called `c` inside the current directory, rather than `/c` in the root of the filesystem.

Instead of setting your `HOME` to `c/Users/<username>`, try `/c/Users/<username>` (with the `/` at the start).